# expected identifier but got '('

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

I am receiving the above mentioned error when compling the code. Can you understand what's the issue?

Thanks

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

interface ITRC20 {
    
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

}

contract Testing {
   ITRC20 trc = ITRC20(0xaf9f549774ecEDbD0966C52f250aCc548D3F36E5);
   trc.transfer(address(this), 255);
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to execute code outside a function.

If you wrap that code in a function it should work on that function invokation.

```
function foobar() public {
   trc.transfer(address(this), 255);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, Ismael. It worked.